# Property Exception using custom IDResolver

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: eclipselink.id-resolver value:   com.persistence.MyIDResolver@4ab34646
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.setProperty(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:332)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.setProperty(UnmarshallerImpl.java:444)
```

Folks, I am getting this property exception using this line of code:

```
jaxbUnmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.ID_RESOLVER, new MyIDResolver());
```

Please help me , i have no idea what i am doing wrong!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First are you sure you need to use a custom `IDResolver`?  Using standard [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) keys are annotated with `@XmlID` and foreign keys are annotated with `@XmlIDREF` and all the joining is done for you automatically.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

`UnmarshallerProperties.ID_RESOLVER` is a property for [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) you will need to be sure you are using MOXy as your JAXB provider to use it.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

If you are using the version of JAXB included in the JDK you can use the following property:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.IDResolver
```

And if you are using the JAXB reference implementation you can use the following property:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.IDResolver
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to set EclipseLink property (org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.UnmarshallerProperties) on Sun's JAXB implementation (currently Oracle). I'm not an expert in EclipseLink but the value of the constant suggests that you should be using MOXy (another JAXB implementation). More on how to configure MOXy:

- [MOXy/JAXB/SpecifyRuntime](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/SpecifyRuntime)